# Implementation of OnSearchBarButtonPressed in the ListView in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to search a name on the table(Listview) in Xamarin Form without using any MonoTouch components - for crossplatform?

I have a number of names and populated on listview and what I want is that once user types the name and listview would be sorted and it should bring to matched name. I have added searchbar at the top of the listview.

I do not know how to implement OnSearchBarButtonPressed method. I believe that I should not reinvent the wheel again.

```
           SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar
            {
                Placeholder = "Search Employee Name",
            };
            searchBar.SearchButtonPressed += OnSearchBarButtonPressed;

            Padding = new Thickness (10, 20, 10, 10);
            Content = new StackLayout () {
                Children={searchBar,listView}

            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to your other posting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308608/listview-object-and-passing-data-to-the-next-view-in-xamarin-form/26309169#26309169) your **ListView ItemsSource** is a collection of objects.

The **ListView** control has *no way of knowing about your model* and *wouldn't be able to any filtering by itself*.

There appears to be nothing inbuilt into the **ListView** that would allow you to specify some **Predicate** to help with this task anyway.

You should therefore do the filtering in the **SearchBar.SearchButtonPressed** and then re-assign the **ListView ItemsSource** to reflect the *newly filtered* **ItemsSource** you want to show to the end-user.  Your filtering logic could then be anything you wanted as your be able to customize this to even filter over many fields etc.

The **SearchBar.SearchButtonPressed** is just an **event** which you assign an **EventHandler**, like you are already doing.  You just need to fill in the filtering logic and update the **ListView** accordingly.