# ListView Object and Passing data to the next View in Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have collected all the information for each of my customer and would like to populate CustomerID information on my initial view which is listView. However, I think I am on one level top of the object and I do not know how to get CustomerID information on my listView.

Also I would like to pass selected item object information to the next view to show the rest of corresponding customer information.

```
private IEnumerable <IDictionary<string,object>> myData;
List <Customer> list= new List<Customer>();
var listView= new ListView();

foreach (var customers in myData) {
    list.Add(new Customer((string)customers["CustomerID"],
                (string)customers ["CompanyName"],
                (string)customers ["ContactName"],
                (string)customers ["ContactTitle"],
                (string)customers ["Address"],
                (string)customers ["Region"],
                (string)customers ["PostalCode"],
                (string)customers ["City"],
                (string)customers ["Fax"],
                (string)customers ["Phone"]
    ));

}
listView.ItemsSource=list;

SearchBar searchBar = new SearchBar
{
    Placeholder = "Xamarin.Forms Property",
};

Padding = new Thickness (10, 20, 10, 10);
Content = new StackLayout () {
    Children={searchBar,listView}
};

listView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {
    //my next view is DetailPage
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **ItemsSource** is a collection of objects.

You will need to create an **ItemTemplate** that will then be used **for each item** within this collection to render from.

Within this **ItemTemplate** you can add various **Xamarin.Forms Cells**, see [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/cells/), or create your own layout by deriving from **ViewCell**.

There is a tutorial with a **ListView** using custom classes [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/), towards the end of the page that will be quite useful to you in both **code-behind** and **XAML** approaches.

It also shows how to take a selected value and pass this on to another page, by looking at the selected value in **listView.SelectedItem** and casting it to your model.